# Media queries doesnt work at all

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I was wondering if anyone could help me with this?
I'm doing a test site and I'm not getting media queries working. I have tried multiple things and googled but I cannot find an answer that solves my problem. The code is:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="row">
                    <img href="index.html" src="resources/images/logo.png" alt="talkFM logo" class="logo">
                    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="omoss.html">Om oss</a></li>
                        <li><a href="kontaktoss.php">Kontakt oss</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </nav>

        <div class="hero-text-box">
            <p class="velkommen">Velkommen til Talk fm</p>
            <h1>Kom i kontakt med vennene dine - on the air. </h1>
            <!--<a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Pr&oslashv n&aring</a>
            <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Sp&oslashr oss</a>-->
            <p class="info">Mobilt radionettverk i Bergen & omegn med god <br>radiodekning. N&aring kan du holde kontakten via din VHF radio.<br> Bli med og opplev gleden med radio du ogs&aring!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-text-img">
            <img src="resources/images/radio_ki.png">
        </div>
    </header>

.hero-text-box h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


@media screen and (max width: 1200px) {    

    .hero-text-box h1 {
        color: black;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your media query it doesn't look like you have '-' between the min and width. Media query should look something like this:

```
@media  (min-width: 1200px) {    

    .hero-text-box h1 {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

The 'and' keyword is used for combining multiple media features together and combining media features with media types. [Check here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Thank you soo much! As my teacher always told me ... Finding your own mistakes, is harder than anything else. lol . Thanks

Comment: No problem! Please remember to accept answer if you found helpful and enjoy all the great learning ahead of you :)

Comment: Hi! Would you know if it is possible when I reach an media query,  I can put the image below a text?

Comment: Yes, the media-queries override any css in the stylesheet as long as you are within the media query width parameters. You can have the image either display: none or visibility: hidden in your regular css and when your media query is enabled use display:block or visibility: visible.